# ksh errexit on conditional execution

Tags: shell, unix, ksh, openbsd

Consider the code:

```
set -ex
for a in 1 2 3; do
  [ $a == 1 ] || false
done
```

The expected output is:

```
+ [ 1 == 1 ]
+ [ 2 == 1 ]
+ false
```

However I get:

```
+ [ 1 == 1 ]
+ [ 2 == 1 ]
+ false
+ [ 3 == 1 ]
+ false
```

For some reason ksh decides not to exit after the `false` on the second iteration.

Running this script through bash provides the expected results.

Interestingly enough, I can convince ksh to provide the expected results by changing the code to:

```
set -ex
for a in 1 2 3; do
  [ $a == 1 ] || false
  true
done
```

Which on the surface, all I'm doing is adding a `true` command that's supposed to effectively do nothing.

My ksh version (the default on OpenBSD 6.0) is: `@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2`

I wanted to make sure that there isn't something I'm missing before I decide to report this as a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't go as far as submitting it as bug, let us look at some history now.

The current existing `Korn` shell versions are

- If the output looks like Version `JM 93u 2011-02-08`, then you have
  [`ksh93`](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Ksh93).
- If the output looks like `@(#)PD KSH v5.2.14 99/07/13.2`, then you
  have [`pdksh (Public Domain Korn Shell)`](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/Public_Domain_Korn_Shell).
- If the output looks like `@(#)MIRBSD KSH R49 2014/01/11`, then you
  have [`mksh (MirBSD Korn Shell)`](https://www.rosettacode.org/wiki/MirBSD_Korn_Shell).

Your `ksh` version falls into the second category which according to this source says,

> pdksh is the public domain **Korn** shell, a clone of the Korn Shell. It has most of the ksh88 features, and almost none of the ksh93 features. The last version, **pdksh 5.2.14** from 1999 July 13, still has several bugs. Systems like Debian, OpenBSD and PLD now apply several patches to `pdksh`.

So no wonder your **ksh** version is pretty outdated, and I tried getting a proper maintenance change-log for your shell version and compare it with the releases in which the patch for your reported issue and I could not find it, no wonder it is no longer maintained.

But the same on a the latest `ksh93` version on my `MacOSX`, **`sh (AT&T Research) 93u+ 2012-08-01`**, running your script produced exactly as you expected,

```
+ [ 1 '==' 1 ]
+ [ 2 '==' 1 ]
+ false
```

Suggest upgrading your **ksh** version for further research as yours is pretty outdated and error-prone, or if you want to still want to report, assuming if there is an active support for this, you can reach out to the mailing-list mentioned in the **Bugs** section of this [pdksh(1) - Linux man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/pdksh).

Answer (score 0):

I believe this has been fixed in -current.

http://marc.info/?t=148076436600001

http://cvsweb.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/cvsweb/src/bin/ksh/exec.c?sortby=date&f=h#rev1.65

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Highly unlikely as the first one is an mailing lists' archive and the second one is the official source code log :^) Nevertheless, thank you for information - I'll bear that in mind.